# How to view a CakePHP plugin view

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, routes

I've been going around and around reading the docs and doing searches, but there isn't a clear explanation of how to reach a plugin view using a web browser.

My plugin is called MediaManager.

I have `CakePlugin::loadAll();` in my `bootstrap.php` file.

I have `CakePlugin::routes();` in my `routes.php` file.

I have `MediaManagerAppController.php` and `MediaManagerAppModel.php` in their respective folders, and I have a `MediaController.php` file with a `MediaManager` class that extends `MediaManagerAppController`, and a `manager function` defined within. In the view folder, I have a view file called `manager.ctp`.

I enter the URL `/MediaManager/Media/manager` into the address bar and I recieve an error that I haven't created a MediaManagerController in my app/Controllers/ directory, so obviously it isn't even trying to access my plugins directory.

I double checked that I was entering the url correctly by copying the output of `$this->Html->url(array('plugin' => 'MediaManager', 'controller' => 'media', 'action' => 'manager'));` I also tried every combination of upper and lower case letters for the parameters just in case.

I've created a `routes.php` file in my `plugin/MediaManager/Config/` directory, and put in a `var_dump`, but it never gets called either.

Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should stick to the convention to use snake_case in your URLs, thus:

```
$this->Html->url(array('plugin' => 'media_manager', 'controller' => 'media', 'action' => 'manager'));
```

which will produce the URL

```
/media_manager/media/manager
```

Even though both versions might work.
Also make sure you clear the cache after adding plugins (or loading new ones).