# How to view a cakephp plugin page

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, cakephp-2.0

I'm making a plugin called "test", as an example.

Is it possible to create "pages" for this plugin and display them?

In my plugin folder I've got a folder called `View`, and inside that another folder called `Pages`, which contains a file: **"demo5.ctp"**

+test  view   Pages    demo5.ctp
+webroot

I'm assuming the link I need to that page would be:

`localhost/test/pages/demo5`

`localhost/[plugin_name]/pages/demo5`

```
echo $this->Html->link('test',array(
                    'plugin'=>'test',
                    'action'=>'demo5',
                    'controller'=>'pages'
                    ));
```

But this gives me a Missing Controller Error? What have I missed or is this not possible?

Comment: Please read question and answer both :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927965/how-to-view-a-cakephp-plugin-view

Comment: Does your Pages Controller belong to the test plugin? Your link will be looking for PagesController in the test plugin's Controller directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments your code is correct, but you need a PagesController in your plugin. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins/how-to-create-plugins.html#plugin-views